# how to execute a source command from php in a server

Tags: php, python

I am unable to execute a source command in linux using php.All other commands are working except this one. I need to execute the following command.

```
 source /root/Envs/ate/bin/activate
```

This activates the ate-Automatic Test Equipment.Once I activate it then I need to run a python script as the script accesses the remote server.
I am able to manually run it but I am creating a tool which will automatically do it.

```
  <?php
  exec("source /root/Envs/ate/bin/activate", $output, $return);
  echo "Command returned $return, and output:\n";
  echo exec("python box_upgrade-pradeepa.py");
  ?>
```

The above commands returns 1 which means there is an error.But I am not sure how to run the 'source command'. The python script will run only if the source command is successful.(the python command is correct as I replaced hello.py and it ran fine.)
Could you pls help me as I am really stuck for a week?
Thanks a lot..

Comment: probably a user\permission issue

Comment: I tried exec(sudo source /root/Envs/ate/bin/activate) and still it returns command 1.

Comment: each of those execs is a SEPARATE shell, which means anything you sourced/created in the first `exec()` call is **GONE** in the second one, because you fired up a different shell.

Comment: Oh yes I didn't  realize that...Then let me give in the same exec. But the source command itself is not working...Thanks a lot for giving this point..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the error. Since I am doing it using php (for a web tool) the user is Apache. 'Apache' user is unable to access the script in root folder. Moving it to another directory, I am able to run the script fine.

Thanks all..